# Connect to MySQL remote host using SQLyog

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, sqlyog

is there any way to connect to a remote database by using `SQLyog`? I have the ip address, user name and password of the database. However, I have `'Error 2203 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '[myIpAddress]'` (10060)'` whenever I test connection in SQLyog.

Comment: Probably this FAQ will help you: http://faq.webyog.com/content/23/15/en/error-no-2003-can_t-connect.html

Answer (score 0):

It means there is no direct access to database ..
You can check by telnet to port 3306 from destination address.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to MySQL remotely using SSH, if the remote MySQL connection is not enabled. Please check the following screenshots:

[image]

[image]